# is it possible to install kerberos for different distros?

Tags: security, kerberos

I want to install kerberos on AlmaLinux as server to manage ubuntu clients.
is this possible? i read somewhere that in order to use kerberos, "[Both devices have the same operating system](https://linuxhint.com/install-kerberos-linux/)".

so both systems must use ubuntu?

thanks

Comment: "I want to install kerberos on AlmaLinux " That is off topic. We know almost nothing about almalinux. Please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/  Mind that from the looks of it almalinux is a REDHAT clone.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked page says ".. explanation of how to set up and design Kerberos **in a Cluster**" and "Introduce Kerberos KDC client on every one of the nodes or machines **in the cluster**..."

So unless you're planning to do just that, the page doesn't seem to be applicable. I'm not aware of any restrictions regarding the client OS.

[The MIT Kerberos Documentation page](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/index.html) is the best place to find up-to-date info.